# Android: Two LinearLayout overlap in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout, android-scrollview

I have an Android layout issue.
I have (1) a ScrollView (2) a TableLayout (3) a footer LinearLayout.
Currently, if the TableRow is too many, the Table will overlap the footer Layout.
The following is my xml layout.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F7F7F7">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/account_section"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Head Text" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="#CCCCCC">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:text="1" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="#CCCCCC">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:text="2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="#CCCCCC">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:text="3" />
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer_section"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/footer_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/footer_image" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/footer_height"
            android:background="#333333">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/usage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Test" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dashboard_copy_right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/copy_right" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If the TableRow is too many, the "table" will overlap the "footer".
How to solve this layout issue?

Thanks in advance.
Eric

Add screenshot
[image]

Comment: It's probably because you've hardcoded the `android:layout_height="100dp"`. Can't you set it to `wrap_content` or `fill_parent` ?

Comment: No, I've tested it, it's not the hard-coded 100dp problem

Comment: Could you post a screenshot that shows the problem?

Comment: Remove scrollView you have set and add scrollview inside LinearLayout tag

Comment: @Apurva But this will result in that "User will always see the footer", right?
But I just want users see the footer only scroll to the bottom.

Comment: @GeorgeD Hi, I've added the screenshot

Comment: Try setting` android:layout_height` to `0dp` and the `android:layout_weight` to `1` of each child of the LinearLayout in order for all of the children to be equally weighted.(http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight)

Comment: @GeorgeD it's nothing to do with weight.

Answer (score 0):

Use this layout and see if it works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer_section" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/account_section"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Head Text" />

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="#CCCCCC" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:text="1" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="#CCCCCC" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:text="1" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="#CCCCCC" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:text="1" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="#CCCCCC" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:text="1" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="#CCCCCC" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:text="1" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="#CCCCCC" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:text="1" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="#CCCCCC" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:text="1" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="#CCCCCC" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:text="2" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="#CCCCCC" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:text="3" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer_section"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/footer_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#333333" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/usage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Test" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dashboard_copy_right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="copy_right" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: not work, the footer text "Test" and "Copy Right" will not show.

Comment: Not work, if the TableRow is not many, the footer should be at the bottom of the screen, not below the Table

Comment: You can aslo make use of framelayout